# Something wrong with Debian kernel dependency

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze

I try to install some packages, but I got this:

```
mail:/home/roland# apt-get install libapache2-mod-geoip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-geoip : Depends: libgeoip1 (>= 1.4.7~beta3+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-2.6-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I try, what the error suggest:

```
mail:/home/roland# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libatk1.0-0 libts-0.0-0 libmime-types-perl libc-client2007b libgtk2.0-common libxfixes3 libgsf-1-common hicolor-icon-theme libfile-remove-perl libxcomposite1 automake1.4
  libltdl3-dev libmd5-perl libilmbase6 libatk1.0-data djvulibre-desktop libdirectfb-1.0-0 fam libxinerama1 libcroco3 libopenexr6 libmail-box-perl libdjvulibre21
  openssl-blacklist libdb4.5 libsysfs2 libbeecrypt6 libxdamage1 libobject-realize-later-perl libuser-identity-perl libxcursor1 portmap libxrandr2 libltdl3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64
Suggested packages:
  linux-doc-2.6.32
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 168 not upgraded.
154 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/28,7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 100 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 38090 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64 (from .../linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64_2.6.32-41_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64_2.6.32-41_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/catc.ko': No space left on device
configured to not write apport reports
                                      dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Running postrm hook script /sbin/update-grub.
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-amd64
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 2.6.32-5-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-2.6.32-5-amd64_2.6.32-41_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I think this is the real error:

```
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/usb/catc.ko': No space left on device
```

Here is a list with the partitions:

```
mail:/home/roland# di
Filesystem         Mount              Mebis     Used    Avail %Used fs Type
/dev/sda1          /                  326,6    283,4     26,4  92%  ext3
udev               /dev                10,0      0,1      9,9   1%  tmpfs
tmpfs              /dev/shm          4003,5      0,0   4003,5   0%  tmpfs
/dev/sda9          /home           249825,7  67012,7 170122,6  32%  ext3
tmpfs              /lib/init/rw      4003,5      0,0   4003,5   0%  tmpfs
/dev/sda8          /tmp               372,2     10,5    342,5   8%  ext3
/dev/sda5          /usr              4694,2    913,6   3542,2  25%  ext3
/dev/sda6          /var              2818,1    565,0   2110,0  25%  ext3
```

Do you know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running out of space during the install. The directory "/lib/modules" is part of the "/" mount which has 26MB free.

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd as you appear to have (what I would think) enough disk space in /var to be able to install packages. However, try doing

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
```

first and then try installing the kernel. This will remove those old packages `apt-get` is referring too and then remove any unused cached .deb files that might be using up space.

It is a bit odd that you haven't got a kernel installed correctly at the moment unless you have selected/deselected one previously.